# Command-line tool for cloning repositories

Tags: command-line, version-control

I'm looking for a command-line tool that works with a variety of version control systems (Git, SVN, Mercurial, …) and clones a remote or local repository to specified folder, e.g.,

```
cloner \
    --source git@gitlab.kitware.com:vtk/vtk.git \
    --out $HOME/vtk
```

Ideally, the tool does some caching (in `/tmp/` or `/var/cache`) such that repeated clones happen faster.

Comment: So what you want is a tool that works with any version management system with the ability to clone to a folder that you specify.. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org), *(hg)*, and [tortoisehg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) *which I recommend installing as it pre-populates some of the extensions for you*, with some plug in components **as a full client** for:

- Mercurial, *(obvious I know)*
- Git, with [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.com/).
- Subversion, with [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home)
- Perforce, with [Perfarce](http://www.kingswood-consulting.co.uk/hg/perfarce/)

You can also use the [convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) to create a hg clone of the repository from:

- CVS
- Subversion
- Git
- Darcs
- Monotone
- Bazaar
- GNU Arch
- Mercurial
- Perforce

This can be done incrementally and once you have converted to hg you can switch to any given revision up to the point that you last updated without even web access.

*Disclaimer: I have contributed to the hgsubversion plug in but gain no financial benefit from it.*